# Javascript gives me NaN and I don't know why

Tags: javascript, html, css

I would like the `punktzahl` to increase by 5 points when I click on "Kleine Straße (=button)" and I no longer get `NaN` as a `punktzahl`.

This is my Code (It's German):

```js
starteSpiel();

function starteSpiel() {
  var Punktzahl = 0;
  document.getElementById("punktzahl").innerText = Punktzahl;
}

function sonderKarte(Punktzahl) {
}

function Mittelwert(Punktzahl) {
  document.getElementById("MittelwertAusgabe").toggleAttribute ("hidden");
}
        
function Chance(Punktzahl) {
  document.getElementById("ChanceAusgabe").toggleAttribute ("hidden");
}

function VollesHaus(Punktzahl) {
}

function KleineStraße(Punktzahl) {
  var KleineStraßePunkte = 5;

  Punktzahl += KleineStraßePunkte;
  document.getElementById("punktzahl").innerText = Punktzahl;
}

function GroßeStraße(Punktzahl) {
}

function Gleiche3(Punktzahl) {
}

function Gleiche4(Punktzahl) {
}

function Gleiche5(Punktzahl) {
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="de">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>TB_Würfelspiel</title>
    <style>
        body {
            background-color: black;
            color: aliceblue;
            margin-left: 5vh;
        }

        .buttonAussehen {
            display: flex;
            flex-direction: column;
            margin-top: 5px;
            font-size: 10px;
        }
        .PunkteAusgabe{
            display: flex;
            flex-direction: row;
            font-size: 15px;
        }
    </style>
</head>

<body>
    <div>
        <pre class="PunkteAusgabe">Du hast <span id="punktzahl" class="PunkteAusgabe"></span> Punkte erreicht! </pre>

        <button class="buttonAussehen" id="Mittelwert" onclick="Mittelwert()">Mittelwert</button>
        <button class="buttonAussehen" id="Chance" onclick="Chance()">Chance</button>
        <button class="buttonAussehen" id="VollesHaus" onclick="VollesHaus()">Volles Haus</button>
        <button class="buttonAussehen" id="KleineStraße" onclick="KleineStraße()">Kleine Straße</button>
        <button class="buttonAussehen" id="GroßeStraße" onclick="GroßeStraße()">Große Straße</button>
        <button class="buttonAussehen" id="Gleiche3" onclick="Gleiche3()">3 Gleiche</button>
        <button class="buttonAussehen" id="Gleiche4" onclick="Gleiche4()">4 Gleiche</button>
        <button class="buttonAussehen" id="Gleiche5" onclick="Gleiche5()">5 Gleiche</button>

        <br>
        <br>

        <div id="MittelwertAusgabe" hidden>
        <p id="ZahlErklärungMittelwert">Bitte gib den Mittelwert ein!</p>
        <input type="number" id="MittelwertZahl">
        </div>

        <div id="ChanceAusgabe" hidden>
        <p id="ZahlErklärungChance">Bitte gib alle Augenzahlen ein!</p>
        <input type="number" id="ChanceZahl">
        </div>

    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

I'm developing my own dice game and don't know why I'm being issued `NaN`.
I have searched the internet for 13 days and also asked Chat GPT, but I have not found anything that would have helped me.

I would be happy if someone could help me.

When the game comes out, the username of the person would be listed as the creator!

Comment: For one, you're not passing anything to `KleineStraße()`. Check that the value you're adding to isn't a string; as values and innerText tend to be.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a function defined like this:

```js
function KleineStraße(Punktzahl) {
  var KleineStraßePunkte = 5;

  Punktzahl += KleineStraßePunkte;
  document.getElementById("punktzahl").innerText = Punktzahl;
}
```

And then you call it like this `onclick="KleineStraße()"`

That function is expecting a number to be passed to it with the `Punktzahl` parameter, and you aren't passing anything to it.

To fix this you need to pass the value you want, like this: `onclick="KleineStraße(1)"`

---

However, reading over your code, it looks like you may be new to how variables work inside functions.  You have a variable defined inside one function, and then you have a parameter on all other functions with the same name, these are not connected in any way even though you named them the same thing. I think something like this might be what you intended to write:

```js
//Define this variable out here so that all the functions can use it
var Punktzahl = 0;

function starteSpiel() {
  document.getElementById("punktzahl").innerText = Punktzahl;
}

function sonderKarte() {
}

function Mittelwert() {
  document.getElementById("MittelwertAusgabe").toggleAttribute ("hidden");
}
        
function Chance() {
  document.getElementById("ChanceAusgabe").toggleAttribute ("hidden");
}

function VollesHaus() {
}

function KleineStraße() {
  var KleineStraßePunkte = 5;

  Punktzahl += KleineStraßePunkte;
  document.getElementById("punktzahl").innerText = Punktzahl;
}

function GroßeStraße() {
}

function Gleiche3() {
}

function Gleiche4() {
}

function Gleiche5() {
}

//Call the function last, so that all the functions exist before it!
starteSpiel();
```

```css
body {
    background-color: black;
    color: aliceblue;
    margin-left: 5vh;
}

.buttonAussehen {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    margin-top: 5px;
    font-size: 10px;
}
.PunkteAusgabe{
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    font-size: 15px;
}
```

```html
<div>
    <pre class="PunkteAusgabe">Du hast <span id="punktzahl" class="PunkteAusgabe"></span> Punkte erreicht! </pre>

    <button class="buttonAussehen" id="Mittelwert" onclick="Mittelwert()">Mittelwert</button>
    <button class="buttonAussehen" id="Chance" onclick="Chance()">Chance</button>
    <button class="buttonAussehen" id="VollesHaus" onclick="VollesHaus()">Volles Haus</button>
    <button class="buttonAussehen" id="KleineStraße" onclick="KleineStraße()">Kleine Straße</button>
    <button class="buttonAussehen" id="GroßeStraße" onclick="GroßeStraße()">Große Straße</button>
    <button class="buttonAussehen" id="Gleiche3" onclick="Gleiche3()">3 Gleiche</button>
    <button class="buttonAussehen" id="Gleiche4" onclick="Gleiche4()">4 Gleiche</button>
    <button class="buttonAussehen" id="Gleiche5" onclick="Gleiche5()">5 Gleiche</button>

    <br>
    <br>

    <div id="MittelwertAusgabe" hidden>
    <p id="ZahlErklärungMittelwert">Bitte gib den Mittelwert ein!</p>
    <input type="number" id="MittelwertZahl">
    </div>

    <div id="ChanceAusgabe" hidden>
    <p id="ZahlErklärungChance">Bitte gib alle Augenzahlen ein!</p>
    <input type="number" id="ChanceZahl">
    </div>

</div>
```